# Unity: Game objects in scene load incrementally and not at the same time

Tags: unity, c#, android

I am using Unity in my Android app. When the app opens, I show the user data in the Unity scene. User data contains texts and images.

In order to load this data in the scene, I make a lot of 
`UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(GameObject,Function,Params)`
calls to many `C#` scripts in Unity from Android. Each of these calls performs a specific task like loading an image, creating a text, applying the text font etc.

Problem is that the loading of this data right now looks incremental (if that's the right word). So the text is visible first and after a fraction of a second the image shows. Some text effects show later. This looks ugly.

How can I make all the UI elements load at the same time even if it takes some time? Is there a way to freeze the scene before each game object is ready to be drawn?

Comment: You could choose to show a loading animation until your app finishes loading the last image, or until you send an "Okay, ready to reveal" message to trigger your scripts to switch to displaying the now-fully loaded content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to wait until something happens:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitUntil.html

Or you can set up a load scene, where you load up and store stuff, than show it in the next scene when is is ready, or when the player presses a button:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html